# Differentiable function whose level set is non-convex, compact, simply connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus, convex-geometry

Is it possible to construct a differentiable function $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ such that the zero level set
$$\mathcal S = \{x \in \mathbb R^n : f(x) = 0\}$$
is non-convex, compact, simply connected, and non-empty? If so, how might we write an explicit formula for $f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$? Is the aforementioned compactness essential to such a construction?

Comment: $f(x)=d(x,K)^2$ where $K$ is, let's say, a [peanut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_oval) with its interior with smooth boundary. For non-compact you can take $K$ the union of a sequence of copies of those peanuts that tends to $\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n = 1$ it is impossible because any connected subset of $\mathbb R$  is an interval.

For $n \ge 2$ let us first give non-compact examples.

Let $q : \mathbb R  \to \mathbb R, q(t) = e^t$ and $g : \mathbb R^n  \to \mathbb R, g(x) = x_1^2 + \dots + x_n^2 - 1$. These are $C^\infty$-functions. Now define
$$f = g \circ (id_{\mathbb R^{n-1}} \times q) .$$
$d = id_{\mathbb R^{n-1}} \times q$ establishes a diffeomorphism between $\mathbb R ^n$ and $\mathbb R^{n-1} \times (0,\infty)$. We have $g^{-1}(0) = S^{n-1}$ so that $S = g^{-1}(0) \cap \left( R^{n-1} \times (0,\infty) \right)$ is an open hemisphere which is simply connected. It is now easy to see that $f^{-1}(0) = d^{-1}(S)$ is not convex, but simply connected.

For $n \ge 3 $ compact examples are given by $g$ since $g^{-1}(0) = S^{n-1}$. To cover also $n = 2$, we proceed as follows.

The function $r : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, r(t) = e^{-1/t^2}$ for $t > 0$ and $r(t) = 0$ for $t \le 0$  is $C^\infty$, thus so is $h : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R, h(x_1,\dots,x_n) = r(x_n)$. Now define
$$f = g^2 + h .$$
Since $g^2$ and $h$ are non-negative, $x$ is a zero of $f$ iff $g(x)^2 = 0$ and $h(x) = 0$. This means that $x \in S^{n-1}$ and $x_n \le 0$, i.e. $f^{-1}(0)$ is a closed hemisphere of $S^{n-1}$ which is simply connected and not convex.

Comment: Thank you for this very insightful answer. To clarify, it seems that you’re using the terms “open” and “connected” with respect to a space of dimension $n-1$. In contrast, the term “non-convex” is used with respect to the space of dimension $n$, as opposed to “non-convex” as a property of (say) a surface in the case $n=3$. Is my understanding appropriate?

Comment: Connectedness is a property of topological spaces which is independent of dimension (but in my answer the spaces in fact have dimension $n-1$). Convexity is a property of subsets of real vector spaces, again this does not depend on dimension. I used the word "open" to denote an open hemisphere of $S^{n-1}$ which means that we consider the points $(x_1,\dots, x_n) \in S^{n-1}$ such that $x_n > 0$.

Comment: Thank you again. Everything makes sense now. As an aside, it’s clear to me that these definitions are independent of dimension; I was vaguely using the dimensions of these spaces to distinguish between their topologies (because, surely, any hemisphere of $S^{n-1}$ does not belong to the standard metric topology of $\mathbb R^n$, but such a hemisphere might still be open in a certain subspace topology, and your last statement is what clarifies this).